# RestSharp POST not working

Tags: c#, json, winforms, desktop, restsharp

I'm building a client-server desktop app in C# and RestSharp seems to be tripping my program up somewhere. The oddest thing is that other POSTs are working to the same Node.js server app.

Here's my code using RestSharp:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://"+Configuration.server);
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("sync", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("added", Indexer.getAddedJson());
request.AddParameter("removed", Indexer.getRemovedJson());

RestResponse<StatusResponse> response = (RestResponse<StatusResponse>)client.Execute<StatusResponse>(request);
e.Result = response.Data;
```

This doesn't work - and by that I mean it doesn't make a call to the server at all. I've verified this using Fiddler too.

But this does work:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["added"] = Indexer.getAddedJson();
    data["removed"] = Indexer.getRemovedJson();

    var resp = wb.UploadValues("http://" + Configuration.server + "/sync", "POST", data);

}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me what's going on. I don't want to stop using RestSharp just for this request, other POST requests are working just fine!

It's not a deserialization problem, because response.Content is null. I'm getting a StatusResponse in the other calls as well so this is probably not the issue.

Comment: Point of clarification.  Is this the ACTUAL code or did you take a snippet?  I ask because you have unbalanced ()'s `RestResponse<StatusResponse> response = RestResponse<StatusResponse>)client.Execute<StatusResponse>(request);` <-- in that statement.  I just want to make sure it's not an issue of "it doesn't compile so it's running off of old code."

Comment: It's actual code, accidentally deleted the bracket while indenting for SO. Fixed now.

Comment: One more point of clarification.  When you said you've tested and it doesn't call the server, you've set a breakpoint in the method and are seeing that it doesn't get called?  I don't dev in node.js, but I assume you can set a BP in the server to check?  What's the signature look like vs another "working" signature?  Just trying to narrow things down.  Ignore me if I'm not helping ;)

Comment: It looks exactly the same. Exactly. And no call is being made because the server never receives any HTTP traffic at all.

Comment: A stab in the dark here... What if you rename the method from sync to something else?  Some service systems allow a /sync/ vs /async/ call to the service endpoint.  Call it synchronize and see if it works.